# can not make ajax call in desired way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to fetch JSON data when `option` of the `select` is selected my javascript code is

```js
var root = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
            $(function(){
                var log = $('#log');
                $('#comment').alwaysChange(function(val){
                    print('SELECTED '+ val);

                    $.ajax({
                      url: root,
                      method: 'GET'
                    }).then(function(data) {
                      console.log(data);
                    });
                });
                
                function print(text){
                    log.prepend('<p>' + text + '</p>');
                }
            });




            $.fn.alwaysChange = function(callback){
                return this.filter('#comment').each(function(){
                    var elem = this;
                    var $this = $(this);
                    
                    $this.change(function(){
                        callback($this.val());
                    }).focus(function(){
                        elem.selectedIndex = -1;
                        elem.blur();
                    });
                });
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="comment">
<option>Select...</option>
<option>Yes</option>
<option>No</option>
</select>

<br/>

<div id="log"></div>
```

the above code is working as wanted, but I want to have two `<select>` elements as

```
<select id="num">
        <option>Select...</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
</select>
<br/>
<select id="comment">
        <option>Select...</option>
        <option>Yes</option>
        <option>No</option>
</select>
```

after this I want to get value of selected `<option>` of select element with id `#num` and build the ajax url as

```
var root = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts' + "value of selected `<option>` of select element with id `#num`" + "if value of selected `<option>` of select element with id `#comment` is 'Yes' then add '/comments' at the end of the url else nothing be added";
```

I have tried in this way

```js
var root = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
            $(function(){
                var log = $('#log');
                $('#comment').alwaysChange(function(val){
                    if(val == "Yes"){
                        $.ajax({
                          url: root+"/"+$('#num option:selected').text() + "/comments", 
                          method: 'GET'
                        }).then(function(data) {
                          console.log(data);
                        });
                    }else{

                        $.ajax({
                          url: root,
                          method: 'GET'
                        }).then(function(data) {
                          console.log(data);
                        });
                    }
                });
                
                function print(text){
                    log.prepend('<p>' + text + '</p>');
                }
            });




            $.fn.alwaysChange = function(callback){
                return this.filter('#drop-location').each(function(){
                    var elem = this;
                    var $this = $(this);
                    
                    $this.change(function(){
                        callback($this.val());
                    }).focus(function(){
                        elem.selectedIndex = -1;
                        elem.blur();
                    });
                });
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="num">
    <option>Select...</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</select>
<br/>
<select id="comment">
    <option>Select...</option>
    <option>Yes</option>
    <option>No</option>
</select>

<br/>

<div id="log"></div>
```

but the above code does not work

Comment: `this.filter('#comment').each`  ... ID's must be unique...so using `each` is redundant on a single element. The rest gets a bit confusing if you are duplicating other ID's also. So need to see some parent structure for these repeating elements

Comment: *"but the above code does not work"* ... not a very good technical problem description...what does work and what doesn't and what does happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `#drop-location` to `#comment`

see:

```js
var root = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
            $(function(){
                var log = $('#log');
                $('#comment').alwaysChange(function(val){
                    if(val == "Yes"){
                        $.ajax({
                          url: root+"/"+$('#num option:selected').text() + "/comments", 
                          method: 'GET'
                        }).then(function(data) {
                          console.log(data);
                        });
                    }else{

                        $.ajax({
                          url: root,
                          method: 'GET'
                        }).then(function(data) {
                          console.log(data);
                        });
                    }
                });
                
                function print(text){
                    log.prepend('<p>' + text + '</p>');
                }
            });




            $.fn.alwaysChange = function(callback){
                this.filter('#comment').each(function(){
                    var elem = this;
                    var $this = $(this);
                    
                    $this.change(function(){
                        callback($this.val());
                    }).focus(function(){
                        elem.selectedIndex = -1;
                        elem.blur();
                    });
                });
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="num">
    <option>Select...</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</select>
<br/>
<select id="comment">
    <option>Select...</option>
    <option>Yes</option>
    <option>No</option>
</select>

<br/>

<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry Man I'm newbie to JS, but your solution works, I have bit back ground in Java, I've a question ___is there any resource on the net which can help me to learn js with exercises/solving real problems?___

Comment: plenty of go to codescool,codeacdemy.w3school,stick @here on SO and you eventually will learn it

Answer (score 1):

i don't understand what this statement does, but i remove it and it works

```
return this.filter('#drop-location').each(function(){
```

plugin should be applied on elements, you are filtering the elements and it results into null hence no event attached to elements.

```js
var root = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
            $(function(){
                var log = $('#log');
                $('#comment').alwaysChange(function(val){
                    if(val == "Yes"){
                       log.text(root+"/"+$('#num option:selected').text() + "/comments")
                    }else{
                     log.text(root)
                    }
                });
                
               
            });




            $.fn.alwaysChange = function(callback){
                    var elem = this;
                    var $this = $(this);
                    
                    $this.change(function(){
                        callback($this.val());
                    }).focus(function(){
                        elem.selectedIndex = -1;
                        elem.blur();
                    });
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="num">
    <option>Select...</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</select>
<br/>
<select id="comment">
    <option>Select...</option>
    <option>Yes</option>
    <option>No</option>
</select>

<br/>

<div id="log"></div>
```